# How jsonValue.isObject() works?

Tags: gwt, getjson, json

Hell i would like to know how  value.isObject()`enter code here` in below code works.

```
String jsonString = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
JSONValue value = JSONParser.parseStrict(jsonString);
JSONObject object =value.isObject();
```

I had same implementation of JSONValue and object in my project, by using  tag

```
<super-source path="">
```

I made gwt to use my implementation instead of GWT's. But using my code I have to add a type cast mechanism for isObject() method.
Here is my code:

```
String jsonString = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
JSONValue value = JSONParser.parseStrict(jsonString);
JSONObject object = (JSONObject)value.isObject();
```

please be free to share your thoughts regarding this.

**UPDATE**
implementation of `isObject()` in my `JSONValue` and `JSONObject`

In JSONValue

```
public JsonObject isObject() {
    return null;
}
```

In JSONObject

```
  @Override
  public JSONObject isObject() {
      System.out.println("is object return this");
    return this;
  }
```

where JSONValue is a abstract class and `class JSONObject extends JSONValue`

Comment: Post the code of your method `isObject` or at least its signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using different objects or you have a uppercase typo: JsonObject in JSONValue vs JSONObject in JSONObject.

Comment: I didn't get you exactly, will you please explain

Comment: Well, in the original class, both methods return a JSONObject, but in your code you are returning JsonObject and JSONObject, unless it is a typo (note the lower-cased chars difference)

Comment: I think it is clear enough, the code you posted here is using different classes JsonObject in JSONValue and JSONObject in JSONObject. JsonObject is spelled different than JSONObject.